# How do I update the wpColorPicker palette after initialization?

Tags: theme-customizer, color-picker

Once the customizer color picker is initialized, how can the color palette be updated? The palette can be set through the js options before it's initialized using something like:

```
jQuery.wp.wpColorPicker.prototype.options.palettes = ["#303f9f", "#5c6bc0", "#e8eaf6", "#ffffff"];
```

Updating the options after the picker is initialized has no effect on the palettes. I'm guessing the picker needs to be reinitialized but can't seem to figure out how to do that inside of the customizer using wpColorPicker.

Comment: Did you ever figure out? I'm in the same situation.